# Stacking list items horizontally, but giving them a 100% width

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am making a testimonials slider and am trying to think of a quick and easy way of sliding through the items.

Currently I have a working version but its not mobile friendly.

My aim (in my head) is to have each testimonial in its own list item, stacked side by side but a container div with overflow hidden only allows one to be shown. I then use javascript to move this div left / right to show a different item.

Here is a current fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/92r3yjc9/3/

As you can see the divs are vertical, I want them horizontal, but keeping 100% width for each one and then in a div that acts a mask.

The markup currently is:

```
    <div class="body-container">
    <ul class="testimonial-holder">
        <li class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more</li>
        <li class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more</li>
        <li class="testimonial">Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more Lorem ipsum and more</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well by setting 100% on the li tags you are forcing them to drop below. You want them to be 100% of what? With 3 items they would need to be 33.3%. Obviously you want a variable number of items in there. I would consider using display:flex on the parent, but that display value is not backwards compatible.. however it's freakin awesome

Comment: I wish only one item to be shown, with the others stacked horizontally but 'off the screen' as per say. Then I can just adjust the position of the containing div

Comment: ohhh I see. Are you planning to use JS to make them move about? otherwise this is not going to look or work as cool as you might be imagining. I'll work on a solution for ya though. Usually it requires your parent to ul to be lets say 9000px wide, then around THAT you need another div with overflow hidden. You still can't set the widths of the li tags to be 100%  because that tells the browser to take 100% of the fill-able space for that item.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/ZbWQWr